# How do I make my site automatically sign out a user when they close their browser?

Tags: php, session, cookies, session-timeout

Let's suppose I have a sign-in form.  When I sign in successfully I am redirected to the logged in home page.  Currently, when I close this page without signing out, and re-open Firefox, this logged in home page is started again.

I want it so that when the user closes their browser the session is the session is expired and when they next open Firefox the logged-in home page isn't displayed.

I think session will be used for this, but I don't know how I can set a time or even make it so that when Firefox closes the closes session get destroyed.

Comment: I've radically edited this to tidy it up, since I couldn't find an obvious duplicate and it's a useful question.

Answer (score 4):

You want the session cookie to have an expire time of 0 - see:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

http://docs.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-lifetime

Answer (score 2):

Set your session timeout to 15 minutes, this should do the job. You cannot catch the "close browser" or "close tab" event for sure (no javascript enabled, browser just crashes, etc), so you shouldn't go for that.

Check Felix' post for additional information where to set the session timeout exactly.

Comment: Happened to me on another thread this morning too.  Apparently on Sunday we're supposed to "just know".

Comment: I'm guessing that it was because of the 15min recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

Pardon me if  I am stepping on toes as non-server HTML programmer, but could you check to see if the browser already has a cookie from a previous session?  Even if the answer is yes, if it is a new session, force an authentication?

Just a thought.