# How to expire the session when the browser window is closed

Tags: php, javascript, web-applications

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [(PHP) how to destroy or unset session when user close the browser without clicking on logout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839988/php-how-to-destroy-or-unset-session-when-user-close-the-browser-without-clicki)

How to expire the session when the browser window is closed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way is capture the window unload event in javascript call your session expire logic.

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

It will already unless you set a cookie. Don't need to do anything

Answer (score 0):

```
<script language="javascript">
function fnUnloadHandler() {
       // Add your code here Write Ajax code to invalidate session  
       alert("Are you sure to close ?");
}
</script>
<body onbeforeunload="fnUnloadHandler()">
<!-- Your page content -->
</body>
```