# remember me with zend_auth

Tags: zend-framework, zend-auth

I use Zend_Auth to log in a user with username and password credentials. But upon closing the browser tab, and opening the website in a new tab, the authentication is remembered by Zend Auth. I need this to happen only if the user checks remember me in the login page. If he hasn't checked it, the authentication should be revoked upon closure of the tab. How do I implement this?

Comment: it's not zend auth but your browser that keeps the cookie until the browser is closed (and not the tab). See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10958769/destroy-session-when-broswer-tab-closed

Answer (score 0):

Send the checkbox value with the form data and see if it was checked or not. If so then just utilize Zend_Session.

```
// set remember me session
if ($formData['loginRememberMe'])
{
    Zend_Session::rememberMe();
}
```