# I want to destroy session like IRCTC or SBI when close the tab of browser

Tags: php, jquery, session

I want to destroy session like IRCTC or SBI when close the tab of browser.
i have also tried ini_set('session.use_cookies',0) but clear session when browser is closed but not when only tab is closed.

i have also tried jquery unload() method and onbeforeunload() but still not working.pls help me.

Comment: Please check marked answer in this link :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24402047/php-session-destroy-after-closing-browser

Comment: Also read this answer(9 vote)- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10958769/destroy-session-when-broswer-tab-closed