# How to destroy session when i close the browser?

Tags: php, ajax, session

Actually I want to show the read more button if the session is not stored and if the session is stored then it is redirected to research.php..

```
                         if (!isset($_SESSION['user'])) {






                      ?>                         

<a href="#" class="ec-colorhover" style="color: #f26530" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1">Read More <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i></a></p>                 


                        <?php
                        }

                        else
                        {
                        ?>
                          <a href="research.php" class="ec-colorhover" style="color: #f26530">Read More <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i></a></p>
```

Comment: I recommend reformating your code so it's more comfortable to read (:

Comment: The answer of the question is here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10958769/destroy-session-when-broswer-tab-closed

Comment: this link could not help please reply me

Comment: @SrrijitaDasgupta  if session available, go to 'research.php' and if not show more button??

Comment: @SrrijitaDasgupta Check my answer

Answer (score 1):

For your question you asked when browser is closed session gets destroyed automatically. So next time when you open the page it will contain 1st link

Answer (score 0):

you can try this way [Destroy PHP Session on closing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4146647/destroy-php-session-on-closing)

```
session_set_cookie_params(0);
session_start();
```

or

By reducing the session timeout, shown here
[How to change the session timeout in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8311320/how-to-change-the-session-timeout-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

Use this code.

```
<?php
session_start();                //session starting
if (isset($_SESSION['user']))   //if session variable user is set?
{
header ('Location: research.php');  //go to research.php
}
else        //else show button
{
?>
<input type="button" value="Readmore" />    
<?php
}
?>
```

Note: But this code should be on top of every code.

And use `unset($_SESSION['user']);` to unset a specific session variable. Here it will unset variable user.